# RStudio keeps crashing

Tags: 14.04, r

My RStudio keeps crashing and its very annoying any help in fixing it will be much appreciated.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

---

```
R --version

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree" Copyright (C)
2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

RStudio Version `0.99.751`

This is from the bottom of `var/crash/_usr_lib_rstudio_bin_rstudio.1000.crash` file

```
No symbol table info available.
Title: rstudio crashed with SIGSEGV in QPainter::drawGlyphRun()
UnreportableReason: This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
```

Comment: @blade19899 I appreciate you editing my question.. but I'm pretty sure it was in good format.. would you at least put `R --version` into its own block.. `R --version` is not part of the `lsb_release -a` cheers

Comment: Version 0.99.751 is some kind of prerelease version? The current version according to https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ is 0.99.489. Version 0.99.489 runs perfectly fine on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @MatthiasDiener this might be it. I actually had 0.99.489 installed (still have .deb file :) ) but for some reason updated to the 0.99.751 thinking that it might be new release or something..I'm testing it out now. You should add this as an answer perhaps with the link to where download it from for others. cheers

Comment: Is version 0.99.489 stable? In that case, I can add this as an answer.

Comment: Yeh, im pretty sure that was it. Had RStudio running all day and it didn't crash once plus I also noticed that there was significant improvement in the speed when editing files in RStudio. I use vim binding and in that 0.99.751 version vim editing was laggy as.. Before RStudio would crash two three hours into runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the reason for the crashes was the pre-release version of Studio (0.99.751). The most current released version (0.99.489) from https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ seems to be stable.